# Can i remove Guest Account completely in Terminal or add a password when logging in even with FileVault enabled?

Tags: terminal, password, filevault

I have a Macbook Pro, with MacOS Montery Version 12.1

Just wondering if there is a way to either completely delete the Guest Account option on my Mac, not just turning it off, through Terminal maybe? Otherwise, is there a way to set a seperate password needed to login to the account? Don't want people to be accessing my computer, just want the use of the Administrator account.

Comment: If you disable it/turn it off, isn't is enough to prevent logins?

Comment: The guest account is needed for 'Find My…' Turning it off will affect functionality. Why do you think you need to disable it?

Answer (score 1):

Just turn it off in **System Preferences→Users & Groups** and people won't be able to use it.